# Limit Client app to access only to a specific web api

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We are configuring a new client app in Azure Active Directory to be used to access a specific web api with Client Credential flow by using the App Registration feature. I would ensure that Azure Active Directory will issue the Authz Token only for a specific registered web api (resource), returning an error in case the target client application request a token for a different resource.
So far we have been able to block access to clients for a specific web api, but what we want is to configure AAD so that a specific client id is able to call only a specific web api (let's say, we want to "change the point of view").
Is there a way to configure a client app on azure AD so that it is able to obtain a token only for a specific resource, regardless how we configure other web api on Azure Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client app may obtain token for different resources but not for non allowed roles (Configured permissions) which are the basis for authorization, not just the token.

Comment: So if no role is defined on the resource, every client app can request the token for it. Is it correct?